# jquery not selecting element from within js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's what works:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElemWidth(){
   var x =  $( "#menuDiv").width();
   alert(x);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getElemWidth()" />
<div id="menuDiv" style="width:250px" />
</body>
```

Here's what doesn't work:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/common.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getElemWidth()" />
<div id="menuDiv" style="width:250px" />
</body>
```

Contents of "common.js":

```
function getElemWidth(){
   var x =  $( "#menuDiv").width();
   alert(x);
}
```

It is calling the function in both cases. I can use jquery in both cases, for example:

```
x = $(window).width();
```

works just fine. For some reason I can't get the document elements from within the .js included file. Is there something I'm missing?

I even added this right below the "common.js" include:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('#menuDiv').width());
  });
  </script>
```

That works perfectly fine. I can reference #menuDiv from within the same file that menuDiv appears, but not in an included javascript file. Is this normal?

Comment: Yeah, that got in there accidentally when I copied it over. That's not in my actual code. The function is getting called, so I'm fairly certain it isn't that.

Comment: `body` and `div` tags **are not self-closing**; could that be the issue?

Comment: @PeterKA I don't think is has anything to do with the div itself, because I am able to reference the div from within the document. I can reference the document or the body from inside the .js file, just not the div.

Comment: What's the mime type of the `common.js`? Can we take a look at your page?

Comment: It's on a closed network. I can set up a dumbed down version on a non-closed network tomorrow if need be. I don't know what the meme type is, it's just a .js file I generated with Dreamweaver, to which I then copied code to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DOM is probably not ready for jQuery to act on it.  The safest point at which to operate on the DOM is after the [document is ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).  The page may be loaded but not fully rendered.  Your common.js should really look like this:

```
function getElemWidth(){
   var x =  $("#menuDiv").width();
   alert(x);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    getElemWidth();
});
```

And your HTML like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/common.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menuDiv" style="width:250px"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/common.js"></script>
</script> <-- this is wrong, remove this extra tag
```

---

Depending on update question:

you should call the function within jQuery DOM ready

```
$(function (){
    getElemWidth();
});
```

and HTML should be

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/common.js"></script>
</head>
<body> <!-- remove onload -->
     <div id="menuDiv" style="width:250px" />
</body>
```

Comment: The jquery.min.js file right below where you say to add the jQuery library is the jQuery library.

Comment: @MarcelMarino yes, nice.

Comment: The extra </script> got in there accidentally when I copied it over. That's not in my actual code. The function is getting called, so I'm fairly certain it isn't that. I updated the question to reflect this. Any other ideas what it could be?